# Apache2 web server crashes randomly

Tags: apache2, mod-wsgi

I've got web serwer on Apache2 that was running for a long time. Lately server is crashing randomly, sometimes after few days, sometimes twice a day. After crash service is running, but all requests are timed-out. In log file is a lot of lines like this:

```
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TSS entry
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TSS entry
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TSS entry
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TSS entry
[Wed May 11 20:03:48.906072 2022] [core:notice] [pid 40827] AH00052: child pid 42720 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed May 11 20:03:48.906112 2022] [core:notice] [pid 40827] AH00052: child pid 42721 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed May 11 20:03:48.906123 2022] [core:notice] [pid 40827] AH00052: child pid 4272 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Could not allocate TSS entry
```

My apache version:
Server version: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Server built:   2021-12-21T16:50:43

OS: Debian 10.10

Python: 2.7.16